# Using Date() in views

Tags: couchdb

Is it ever ok to use Date() in a CouchDB view to filter results based on the current date? I'm thinking it will only update the view if the record is changed?

If that's the case, is there a way of telling a view to reindex every 24 hours?

I realise I could pull all the data out in the view, and then use code to filter, but I'm wondering if there's a way of doing it all in the view.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it may work to store the "last updated" time in the doc, and index on that, then filter where "last updated" is before or after given time.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ever ok to use Date() in a CouchDB view to filter results based on the current date?

The Date() will be computed only during view rebuild so you can not use it to get a query result based on the query time.

> I'm thinking it will only update the view if the record is changed?

The view is updated incrementally when docs are changed and it is completely rebuilt when its definition changes.

> If that's the case, is there a way of telling a view to reindex every 24 hours?

No

> I realise I could pull all the data out in the view, and then use code to filter, but I'm wondering if there's a way of doing it all in the view.

As an alternative you may use [filter functions](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html?highlight=filter#filter-functions) to filter the change feed. These filters are evaluated at query time so you may achieve your purpose with this functionality. Also, [selectors](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-find) may help on this.

Comment: "The view is updated incrementally when docs are changed" -- That's not exactly true. The view is updated when it is queried, for any documents that have been updated since the last view update.  But for the purposes of the OP's question, it's (nearly) equivalent.